# Weather API error: Run-time error '91': Object variable ... not set

Tags: vba, api, openweathermap

Trying a basic API request for current weather to obtain temperature, cloud cover, and precipitation.

This is available online. I was able to successfully run the command button once. Clicking a second time to update with current information failed.

```vb
Private Sub getWeather_Click()

Dim xmlhttp As New MSXML2.xmlhttp, myurl As Object, xmlresponse As New DOMDocument
myurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?apikey=ee9100bd8e6079ca3380ee1d145dda84&mode=xml&units=imperial&q=" & Range("F3").Value
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
xmlresponse.LoadXML (xmlhttp.responseText)
Range("B10").Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/temperature/@value")(0).Text
Range("B11").Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/clouds/@name")(0).Text
Range("B12").Value = xmlresponse.SelectNodes("//current/precipitation/@mode")(0).Text
'MsgBox (xmlresponse.getElementsByTagName("temperature")(0).Attributes(1).Text)  Alternate method to parse XML

End Sub
```

Error is

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

I believe this is referring to the **myurl** object.

Already checked:
-API key
-tools references Microsoftxml3.0 is on
-cleared previously filled cells (B10-B12)

Comment: Regarding the follow up: you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with an answer in the answer space, not an edit to your question.

Comment: Even better, accept the posted answer as it seems to be the fix you implemented.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
myurl As Object
```

to

```
myurl As String
```

[image]